# How to initialize a buffer object's data store with data from PyGLM?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, pyopengl

I use [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) and [PyOpenGL](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL/)

I have specified the following [Shader Storage Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) in the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader):

```c
layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer MVP
{
    mat4 u_proj;
    mat4 u_view;
    mat4 u_model;
} mvp_data;
```

I have initialized the model, view and projection matrix:

```py
model = glm.mat4(1)
view  = glm.lookAt(glm.vec3(0,-3,0), glm.vec3(0,0,0), glm.vec3(0,0,1))
proj  = glm.perspective(glm.radians(90), self.__vp_size[0]/self.__vp_size[1], 0.1, 100)
```

How can the buffer object's data store be created and initialized using [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html) (or `glNamedBufferData`)

```py
ssbo = glGenBuffers( 1 )
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo )
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3*16*4, ???, GL_STATIC_DRAW )
```

respectively initialized by [`glBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferSubData.html)  (or `glNamedBufferSubData`)

```py
ssbo = glGenBuffers( 1 )
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo )
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3*16*4, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW )
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ???, ???);
```

Since the SSBO contains 3 (tightly packed) `mat4`, the size of the buffer is 3 * 16 * 4 (3 4x4-matrices with element data type `float`).
So the initialization of the buffer can be done by a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) array.
But how the PyGLM matrices can be effectively assigned to the NumPy array?

```py
buffer_data = numpy.zeros(3*16, dtype=numpy.float32)

??? buffer_data = model, view, proj

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffer_data.nbytes, buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Or is there an even more efficient solution, without an copying the data to a NumPy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself.

It should be noted, that the [Shader Storage Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) consists of 3*4*4=48 tightly packed floats.

[PyGlm](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) provides the handy functions `glm.value_ptr` and `glm.sizeof`. `glm.value_ptr` corresponds to the [`glm::value_ptr`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00722.html#ga1c64669e1ba1160ad9386e43dc57569a). `glm.sizeof` works like c++ [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) for the *glm* data types.

This functions can be used with the [`glBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferSubData.html) wrapping of [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) to updates the buffer data:

```py
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0,                      glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(model))
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1*glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(view))
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2*glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(proj))
```

A object of type `glm.mat4` can be assigned to a [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with shape `(4, 4)` of type `np.float32`. So the 3 matrices can be assigned to the elements of a `numpy.array` with shape `(3, 4, 4)`:

```py
buffer_data = np.empty([3, 4, 4], dtype=np.float32)
buffer_data[0] = model
buffer_data[1] = view
buffer_data[2] = proj
```

This array can be used to updates the entire buffer data at once:

```py
buffer_size = buffer_data.size * buffer_data.itemsize
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, buffer_size, buffer_data)
```

Or for the initial [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html) creation and initialization of the buffer object's data store:

```py
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffer_data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
```

---

Since PyGLM version 2.0.0 there is a simpler way to l
this. See [Using Arrays](https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyGLM/wiki/Using-arrays):

> PyGLM's array type was introduced in version 2.0.0 to reduce the likelihood of requiring users to also use numpy besides glm. It's mainly intended to provide a way of passing multiple glm type instances (such as vectors) to external C functions
> (such as glBufferData).

```py
buffer_data = glm.array(model, view, proj)
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffer_data.nbytes, buffer_data.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to update all the data at once without having to use numpy at all.

In the PyGLM docs, it says (https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyGLM/wiki/Using-arrays):

> PyGLM's array type was introduced in version 2.0.0 to reduce the likelihood of requiring users to also use numpy besides glm. It's mainly intended to provide a way of passing multiple glm type instances (such as vectors) to external C functions
> (such as glBufferData).

What you can do is to wrap the matrices with a glm.array like this:

```
buffer_data = glm.array(model, view, proj)
```

Then update the data like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffer_data.nbytes, buffer_data.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Note: `nbytes` and `ptr` are built in members of glm.array, and you use them instead of `glm.sizeof` and `glm.value_ptr`.